# Build key/value Object from slash-separated URL

Tags: javascript

Given a slash separated URL like `http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3` how could I build a key/value Object with the dynamic parameters (param1/value, param2/value2...) of this URL?

Valid parameters always have this slash separated `param`and `value` format and `some/fixed/path` would be a substring manually provided.

I tried to split the full URL (or whatever it could be) by the fixed substring and I managed to slice the dynamic params out of it as I wanted but I couldn't create the key/value Object as I needed:

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3";

var uri = "some/fixed/path/";
var result = {};
url.split( uri ).forEach(function(x){
    var arr = x.split('/');
    arr[1] && (result[arr[0]] = arr[1]);
});
console.log( result );
```

But this piece of code only brings me the first pair instead of all of them and it requires the `uri` to obligatorily have a trailing slash. If the substring doesn't have it or has one to the left it acts all weird with a blank key and the first key as value o.O

I know it's simple, but I just can't do it. I tried to search but this must have a very specific way to refer to because I couldn't find by my own.

One last thing, if you don't mind explain instead of just give me the fish, I'd appreciate, so there won't have a next time... hopefully

Comment: url.replace("somefixedpath","").split("/").filter(e=>e);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were only taking the second part after `some/fixed/path/`. You need to split this second part and iterates over the array. On each even index, I create a new property in the object with the name of the previous element

`x` is the current element

`i` is the current index

`a` is the array containing each element after splitting with `/`

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3";

var uri = "some/fixed/path/";
var result = {};
var paramsToSplit = url.split(uri)[1];
paramsToSplit.split('/').forEach((x,i,a)=>{
  if(i%2)
    result[a[i-1]] = x;
});
console.log( result );
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you didn't need an `else`? Anyway your solution has the same caveat I noticed with my attempt. The URI **must** have a trailing slash. Can I react to this? Maybe removing all slashes on both sides and then appending one to the end?

Comment: @user5613506 else is not required as he is accessing previous value using `a[i-1]`.

Comment: I'll need a couple tweaks, like removing existing slashes and adding one to the end manually as well take care of some caveats, like when the fixed path doesn't exist (i.e. `http://www.example.com/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3`), but your solution is the one that covers more terrain. And you explained a bit as I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3";

var uri = "some/fixed/path/";


var url = url.substring(url.indexOf(uri) + uri.length)
var options = url.split('/');
var results = [];

for(var i=0;i<options.length; i+=2){
    results.push({[options[i]]:options[i+1]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for somethig like that?

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3";

var uri = "some/fixed/path/";
var params = [];
var values = [];
var results = {};
url.split( uri )[1].split('/').forEach(function(e,i) {
   if(i%2==0){
     params.push(e)
   } else {
     values.push(e);
   }
})
console.log( params, values );
params.forEach(function(e,i) {
  results[e] = values[i];
   });
console.log( results );
```

Answer (score 0):

You  may do as follows;

```js
var text   = "http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3";
    result = text.split("/")
                 .slice(6)
                 .reduce((r,c,i,a) => i&1 ? Object.assign(r,{[a[i-1]]: c}) : r, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: A pair `fixed` / `path` is not a valid one as it's formed from part of the fixed path that should be removed/ignored/skipped

Comment: @user5613506 I had corrected that but apparently it wasn't refreshed on your page. If you refresh you may see the corrected version.

Comment: I see it now, but like I said to @Rajesh's solution, all parameters keys and values are prefixed with `param` and `value` only here, for the example, so I believe your `slice` won't work on real case scenarios.

Comment: @user5613506 Unlike @Rajesh's solution i am not using any prefix value to select the props and values. I just `.split("/")` the url text into array of strings and trash the first 6. Then reduce does the object conversion job. Items with even indices become a property and the items with odd indices become the value in an orderly fashion.

Comment: Right, but imagine that `some/fixed/path` doesn't exist as defined, that all dynamic parameters are directly attached to the very basic URL structure like `http://www.example.com/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3` (just protocol, domain...). Because you're skipping a predefined number of offsets your code would return an Object with `param2` as they for `value3`

Comment: @user5613506 You need to know what part is fixed. So since you already know (or can resolve) the fixed part finding out that number (6 in this case) is the simplest part so you should be able to implement. Just count the slashes like `[].filter.call("http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/",c => c === "/").length;`

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close, you basically need to make another for loop for your produced arr and step every 2 values. Like so...

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/some/fixed/path/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3";

var uri = "some/fixed/path/";
var result = {};
url.split( uri ).forEach(function(x){
    var arr = x.split('/');

    var step;
    for (step = 0; step <= arr.length; step += 2) {
        arr[step + 1] && (result[arr[step]] = arr[step + 1]);
    }
});

console.log( result );
```